# How can I write a Powershell script to rename all .pst files as their custodian names?

Tags: powershell, csv, rename

I want to match the name variable in the same row as the filename (in this case, *$CSV.name* with *$CSV.filename*), then rename each file accordingly. How would I go about doing this? Any help is much appreciated.

Ideally, I would like to auto-populate a .CSV with two columns: filenames and the custodian names from the email addresses within the filename (e.g. joe.smith@bellsouth.net) using Regex, but I am just getting started with Powershell.

This is what I have written so far. It seems to work well and matches the actual filename to the one in the CSV. However, when I get to the Rename-Item command, it either does nothing or I receive this error:  `Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'NewName'`. I assume this is because it's matching ALL lines and attempting to rename with those instead of just one.

```
Cd "C:\Users\Nick\Downloads\PST"
(
$CSV  = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Nick\Downloads\PST\namesemails.csv' -Delimiter ',' -Header Name, Email, FileName
)

$psts = Get-ChildItem -Path "*.pst"    
#Match filenames to Name column
if((Compare-Object $CSV.filename $psts.name | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=='))
{
    Rename-Item -Path "*.pst" -NewName $CSV.name |foreach {$_ +  ".pst"}
}
```

Comment: Which column of your Csv would be used as the file's new name? Also, if your Csv already has headers, you definitely not need `-Header Name, Email, FileName`

Answer (score 2):

An abstract way to approach this problem assuming you have a Csv that looks like this:

```
"OldName","NewName"
"hello.pst","world.pst"
"foo.pst","bar.pst"
```

Then what I would recommend is to use hash table so you can map the file's `.Name` property with your table's keys and from there get the new name for the file (in this abstracted example, the new name is defined by the `NewName` Column). A simple way to create a hash table is with [`Group-Object -AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3), then you can perform some filtering and renaming pretty easily.

Worth noting:

1. `-Header` is only needed if your Csv does not have headers, for this abstracted example, it would not be needed.
2. `-Delimiter ','` is redundant, `,` is the default delimiter.

```bash
$map = Import-Csv -Path 'namesemails.csv' |
    # group the objects by the `OldName` column
    Group-Object OldName -AsHashTable

# get all `.pst` files
Get-ChildItem -Path '*.pst' |
    # filter only those files existing in our map
    Where-Object { $map.ContainsKey($_.Name) } |
    # here we assume the file exist so, we get the value that maps with
    # this file name and from there we expand the `.NewName`
    Rename-Item -NewName { $map[$_.Name].NewName }
```