# How could I write a script which populates a CSV column with all filenames from a path?

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I would like to get all items in a path with Get-ChildItem, then with regex, match everything in the filename before the '@' (**andrea.figuera**@gmail.com.pst), and capitalize the first letter and the letter after the period. (andrea.figuera becomes Andrea.Figuera). Then, I'd like to remove the '.' and in a CSV, I want to two populate two columns: '*FileName*' and '*Name*', so I can match them and rename the file with the corresponding '*Name*' value.
Is this possible with Powershell? Thank you!

This is the current script that I have, [written by member Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77063193/45375). It works, but I didn't want to implement the CSV editing yet, instead wanting to understand the process one at a time, but I'm bashing my head trying to understand the relevant commands.

```
Cd "C:\Users\Nick\Downloads\MATIC PST"

$map = Import-Csv -Path 'namesemails.csv' |
    # group the objects by the `OldName` column
    Group-Object OldName -AsHashTable

# get all `.pst` files
Get-ChildItem -Path '*.pst' |
    # filter only those files existing in our map
    Where-Object { $map.ContainsKey($_.Name) } |
    # here we assume the file exist so, we get the value that maps with
    # this file name and from there we expand the `.NewName`
    Rename-Item -NewName { $map[$_.Name].NewName }
```

I added this statement to the beginning of the script to match the custodian name within the filename, but I'm not sure if I did this correctly.

```
    $regexpattern = '([^@.]+)\.([^@]+)(?=@)'

    #Get all .pst files and extract custodian names from filenames, if available
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path '*.pst' | Group-Object Name -AsHashTable
    foreach ($file in $files) 
    {
    $file | Select-String $regexpattern -AllMatches
    }
```

Comment: If those are the email addresses of real people, you'll want to edit them before a spambot scrapes this post.

Comment: I would use : $regexpattern = '^[^@]+)'  Beginning of the line until the @ character

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
$path = 'c:\temp\*.pst'
$regexPattern = '(^[^\.]+\.[^@]+)(@.*)'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    if($file.Name -match $regexPattern)
    {
       $name = $Matches[1]
       $name = $name.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + $name.Substring(1)
       $period = $name.IndexOf('.')
       $name = $name.Substring(0,$period) + $name.Substring($period + 1,1).ToUpper() + $name.Substring($period + 2)

       Write-Host $name $Matches[0]
    }
}
```